# Search and return result in array

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection, like so:

```
post = {"topics":["japan","japanese","england","chinese"]}
post = {"topics":["canada","japan"]}
post = {"topics":["usa"]}
```

Now I want to implement a query can return a list of elements by checking the "topics" field to see if it contains a certain character.

For example, query for "ja", it returns all the tags start with "ja":
["japan", "japanese"],

query for "c", returns ["chinese","canada"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not resolve this problem with a single query. You have to maintain either a global list or collection of all tags in order to search them efficiently using regular expressions or you need to iterate over all documents for matching the tags individually for each document.